# intel xdk javascript not work on subpage

Tags: javascript, html, intel-xdk

I have my HTML5 app on Intel XDK with a javascript (funciones.js) that return data to my table with id="resultados", it's work in the main page, but when I nav to a subpage, the javascript not work in the subpage.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="funciones.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <table id="resultados">
    </table>

    <p><a href="page2.html">Navigate to page 2</a></p>
  </body      

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show what your other page looks like to be sure, but one possibility is that you're not reloading `functiones.js` in `page2.html`.  Just like a web page, when you go to a different page it's like running a different app, so you'd need a script tag on that page that loads `functiones.js` as you do on the first page.

However, the fact that a second page is like a different app is one of the reasons developers are strongly advised to use a "Single Page App" approach (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_next_index.md.html#Best%20Practices), so you may want to reconsider this approach and try to do it in a single page.